# Surface terms in the calculus of variations on jet bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, jets

Let $\pi:N\rightarrow M$ be a fibered manifold with $m=\dim M$ and $m+n=\dim N$. The variational bicomplex on the infinite jet space $J^\infty(\pi)$ is denoted $(\Omega^{k,l}(\pi),\delta,\mathbf d)$ with $k$ being the contact/vertical degree, $l$ the horizontal degree, $\delta$ the vertical differential and $\mathbf d$ the horizontal differential.

Let $L\in\Omega^{0,m}(\pi)$ be a Lagrangian of order $r$, then we have the well-known decomposition $$ \delta L= E(L)-\mathbf d\Theta, $$ where $E(L)$ is the Euler-Lagrange form (order $\le 2r$) and $\Theta\in\Omega^{1,m-1}(\pi)$ a current that is non-unique in general but can always be chosen such that it is order $2r-1$ and $\pi^{2r-1}_{r-1}$-horizontal (where $\pi^r_s:J^r(\pi)\rightarrow J^s(\pi)$ the relevant jet projection).

This is the "abstract" first variation formula, which becomes "semi-concrete" if $X$ is some vertical contact vector field on $J^\infty(\pi)$ and we contract the above formula with it, giving $$ \partial_X L=X\rfloor \delta L=X\rfloor E(L)+\mathbf d(X\rfloor \Theta), $$ and becomes "fully concrete" if $\phi\in \Gamma_{\mathrm{loc}}(\pi)$ is some local section of the fibration along with which we pull the above formula back, giving $$ (j^\infty\phi)^\ast\partial_X L=(j^\infty\phi)^\ast(X\rfloor E(L)) +\mathrm{d}(j^\infty\phi)^\ast(X\rfloor\Theta). $$ Since $X\rfloor E(L)$ depends only on the projection of $X$ to $N$, this is an "algebraic" operator on $(\pi^\infty_0)_\ast X$, hence the above decomposition is an integration-by-parts formula and if $\Omega\subseteq M$ is a compact region, and is a subset of the domain of $\phi$, then we have $$ \int_\Omega (j^\infty\phi)^\ast\partial_X L=\int_\Omega (j^\infty\phi)^\ast(X\rfloor E(L))+\int_{\partial\Omega}(j^\infty\phi)^\ast (X\rfloor\Theta), $$ and if appropriate boundary conditions are placed on the contact vector field $X$ (generating a field variation), the surface term vanishes, and one can use the duBois-Raymond lemma to conclude that $E(L)\circ j^\infty\phi=0$ if the integral is to vanish for all admissible choice of $X$.

In the "formal" approach, one does not usually care about all that, and only the various algebraic relations matter. However if one takes the actual variational problem seriously, then it is necessary to deal with the surface term in greater detail.

A particular situation is when one does not impose any boundary conditions on the space of smooth sections over $\Omega$ (and hence on the admissible "variations" $X$), then the condition for the integral to vanish involve both bulk and boundary equations. The boundary equations are known as *natural boundary conditions*.

My question essentially boils down to how one may obtain the natural boundary conditions "explicitly".

---

It is possible to deal with this problem "locally" in a rather ugly manner. Let's introduce fibered coordinates $(U,x,u)$ on $N$ with $x=(x^i)=(x^1,\dots,x^m)$ and $u=(u^\sigma)=(u^1,\dots,u^n)$. I'll also change perspective a bit, $X$ will now be a vertical generalized vector field on $N$ and the previous notion of $X$ is now the prolongation $\mathrm{pr}\,X$. Let's write $\Theta(X):=\mathrm{pr}\,X\rfloor \Theta$. Then in coordinates we have $$ \Theta = \sum_{|I|=0}^{r-1}\Theta^{iI}_\sigma \delta u^\sigma_I\wedge  (\mathrm dx)_i,\quad(\mathrm dx)_i=\partial_i\rfloor \mathrm d x,\quad \mathrm d x=\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^m, $$ so $$ \Theta(X)=\sum_{|I|=0}^{r-1}\Theta^{iI}_\sigma X^\sigma_I(\mathrm d x)_i,\quad X=X^\sigma\frac{\partial}{\partial u^\sigma},\quad X^\sigma_I=d_IX^\sigma,\quad d_I=d_{i_1}\dots d_{i_k}, \quad d_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}+\sum_{|I|<\infty}u^\sigma_{iI}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^\sigma_I}. $$

Let also $\delta\phi^\sigma=X^\sigma\circ j^\infty\phi$, and for simplicity let us consider all jet objects to be pulled back along $j^\infty\phi$ without any additional notation. Introduce coordinates $x=(y,t)$ adapted to the boundary $\partial\Omega$ such that $\partial\Omega$ is given by $t=0$. Then we have (implicitly pulled back to $\partial\Omega$) $$ \Theta(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\Theta^{ti_1...i_k}_\sigma\delta\phi^\sigma_{i_1...i_k}\,\mathrm d y=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\sum_{i_1\le\dots\le i_k}\Theta^{\prime ti_1...i_k}_\sigma\delta\phi^\sigma_{i_1...i_k}\mathrm d y,$$ where $\Theta^{\prime ti_1...i_k}_\sigma$ is related to the unprimed version by a multinomial factor (depending on $i_1...i_k$) which I am too lazy to compute now. Then this can be further decomposed as $$ \Theta(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\sum_{p=0}^{k}\Theta^{\prime\prime(p+1)ta_1...a_{k-p}}_\sigma\delta\phi^\sigma_{(p)ta_1...a_{k-p}}\mathrm d y, $$ where $(p)t$ means that $t$ appears $p$ times, and the indices $a_1,\dots$ run over the range of the $y$ coordinates.

Then we can integrate by parts over the "spatial" derivatives ("spatial" meaning with respect to the $y$ coordinates) and obtain an expression of the form $$ \Theta(X)=\sum_{p=0}^{r-1}\Pi^{(p+1)}_\sigma \delta\phi^\sigma_{(p)t}\mathrm d y+\mathrm d_{(y)}(\dots), $$ where $\mathrm d_{(y)}$ is the exterior derivative acting on the $y$ coordinates only. Since $\partial\Omega$ is closed, we obtain that the natural boundary conditions are equivalent to $$ \Pi^{(p)}_\sigma=0\quad(\text{along }\partial\Omega),\quad 1\le p\le r. $$ This is because at $t=0$ the field variations $\delta\phi^\sigma, \delta\phi^\sigma_t,\dots,\delta\phi^\sigma_{(r-1)t}$ are independent functions. Due to the coordinate conditions this is valid only locally, but since we can always choose field variations with arbitrary narrow support, these equations do hold in each adapted coordinate chart separately. However the objects $\Pi^{(p)}_\sigma$ have horrible transformation properties under changes of adapted charts and it is unclear how to assemble them into anything resembling an actual geometrical object.

---

**Actual question**: I would like to know if there is any developed formalism which is capable of handling anything resembling the above computation in a reasonably global and coordinate-free manner. That is - if we have an $m$-form $\Theta\in\Omega^{1,m-1}(\pi)$ as above and $X$ is a vertical generalized vector field - to be somehow able to define and decompose some kind of "formal pullback" of $\Theta$ to $\partial\Omega$ in a way that there is a global/invariant integration-by-parts formula for it on $\partial\Omega$ similar to the decomposition of a Lagrangian on the jet bundle over $N\rightarrow M$.

Evidently, this is related to the problem of relating the pulled back jet bundle $\left.J^\infty(\pi)\right|_{\partial\Omega}$ to the jet bundle $J^\infty(\left.\pi\right|_{\partial\Omega})$ computed on the pullback of $\pi$ to $\partial\Omega$. I do not know whether such relations are known to exist.

Ideally, if such a formalism exists, it would be capable of expressing the natural boundary conditions of a variation problem such that the restrictions of certain global forms to graphs of prolongations of sections along the boundary must vanish.

Comment: There is a closely related problem which concerns the improvement of canonical Noether currents associated with symmetries of the action functional(s). In the case of the stress-energy tensor, for instance, $X$ is necessarily some lift of a vector field $X_M$ on $M$ and thus is *never* vertical. However, if one requires $X\rfloor\Theta$ to be *ultralocal* (that is, it depends only on point values of $X_M$ and not on the latter's derivatives), then at least for first-order Lagrangians this *uniquely* singles out $\Theta$.

Comment: One can apply the same procedure to uniquely improve the canonical Noether current associated to any *local* infinitesimal symmetry of first-order action functional(s), like local gauge symmetries (in the latter case, $X$ happens to be vertical). I don't know if this still works for higher-order Lagrangians, though. My Physics.SE answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/256496/16767 explains this in more detail.

Comment: The inclusion $\partial \Omega \to M$ is induces a pullback differential graded algebra morphism $\Omega^\bullet(M) \to \Omega^\bullet(\partial\Omega)$. The kernel of the pullback is an ideal that is globally defined. Locally, using your local $(y,t)$ chart, this ideal is generated by $t$ and $dt$. You can filter $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ and by extension $\Omega^{\bullet,\bullet}(J^\infty(\pi))$ by the powers of this ideal. All your coordinate formulas can be interpreted essentially as writing local decompositions that are compatible with this filtration.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks this sounds like a promising approach, though it is not entirely clear how to transfer this filtration over to the bicomplex, it is not a functor w.r.t maps between base spaces. Do you know any publication which considers the problem in the OP?

Comment: $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ acts on $\Omega^{\bullet,\bullet}(J^\infty(\pi))$ by multiplication.

Comment: Maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2985